# Charset on Strato Server

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, character-encoding

i have to move a clients wordpress to a strato server.

Everything worked out so far. But all typing with umlaut in german. So ü becomes a ?. 
I figured out that this has to do with the charset.

Heres's my database configuration:
[image]

The coallation of the database is `utf8mb4_unicode_ci` as well.

And this is my html header on the page:

```
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Type:text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date:Wed, 18 Nov 2015 12:58:52 GMT
Keep-Alive:timeout=3, max=100
Link:<https://mydomain.de/>; rel=shortlink
Server:Apache/2.2.31 (Unix)
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
X-Pingback:http://mydomain.de/xmlrpc.php
X-Powered-By:PHP/5.5.29
```

I tried now with `defaul_charset=UTF-8` in php.ini but that did not bring a change.

What am I doing wrong? In phpMyAdmin I ca see the öäüß are spelled correctly.

Answer (score 0):

One of two things:

1)
Make sure any string processing in your PHP code is using the `mb_` (multibyte-safe) variants.  E.g. `mb_substr` instead of `substr`.

2)
Make sure your php code is connecting to the DB in a utf-8 manner:

mysqli:

```
$DB->set_charset('utf8mb4');
$DB->query("SET NAMES 'utf8mb4'");
```

PDO:

```
$DB = new PDO('mysql:charset=utf8mb4');
$DB->exec("SET NAMES 'utf8mb4'");
```

Comment: sounds great. Where do I do that?